# Zabbix - options for Proxy on a Windows server

Tags: zabbix, zabbix-agent

I need to monitor remote customer sites that are only Windows based, with no virtualisation. I'd like to run the Zabbix Proxy on the server so I can monitor the rest of the network.

As there's no Zabbix Proxy for Windows as far as I an tell, what other options are people using? I've thought of installing Docker or similar to run a bare Zabbix Proxy under a Linux environment, but wondered if there's a better way to do it.

I have the Agent on the Windows server running in Active mode, but obviously, this only handles one device and can't do SNMP etc.

Answer (score 1):

Using the new Windows Subsystem for Linux feature you can install a zabbix server or a proxy on windows 2019 or Windows 10 easily. I have created an installation guide for zabbix proxies. [How to install Zabbix Proxy on Windows](http://www.solutioning.eu/2019/05/08/how-to-install-zabbix-proxy-on-windows/)

Comment: Nice one! That looks to be a good option.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that with "no virtualisation" you mean "no existing virtualisation". Two options:

- run a Linux virtual machine with a proxy; in this case, availability depends on the host Windows machine
- deploy proxy on a small form factor system, call it "Monitoring appliance"

Comment: Thanks Richlv. I don't particular want to run a VM on the current Windows Server if I can get away with it, but I had considered using something like a Raspberry Pi. It's a shame there isn't an official Proxy package for Windows however